# React application freezes using custom async/await function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, random

I'm working on a personal project and are experiencing problems with my application freezing in certain situations. It loads correctly when I redirect the first time, but if I try to change something in my code and React then re-renders, my application just freezes. It has to do with something in regards to my async function that finds x number of random elements in a list and returns that. (Also makes sure that it does not choose the same as the user has chosen).

Can someone see any problems in my function that they think may cause these problems? I've created a codesandbox example that is almost identical to the code I'm using.

https://codesandbox.io/s/async-fire-z28xq?file=/src/App.js

Also here is my generate random function;

```
export async function getRandomFighters(amount, selected) {
  const dataCopy = [
    { id: 1, label: "Test1" },
    { id: 2, label: "Test2" },
    { id: 3, label: "Test3" },
    { id: 4, label: "Test4" },
    { id: 5, label: "Test5" }
  ];
  const fighters = [];

  while (fighters.length !== amount) {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dataCopy.length);
    const selectedIndex = dataCopy.findIndex((e) => e.id === selected.id);

    if (randomIndex === selectedIndex) {
      continue;
    }

    const randomFighter = dataCopy.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
    fighters.push(randomFighter);
  }

  return fighters;
}
```

The method is called within a componentDidMount;

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        const fighters = await getRandomFighters(4, this.props.selected_fighter);
        this.setState({opponents: fighters});
    }
```

Comment: do u get any error?

Comment: Is the issue reproducing for you in your codesandbox? I don't notice any freezing/issue in your sandbox. I see a potential bad case where the random index is the wrong index every time, but that seems unlikely. It also isn't clear why you've marked `getRandomFighters` as an `async` function since all the code in it is completely synchronous and you don't `await` anything.

Comment: where and when it exactly freezes?

Comment: The issue with freezing is only happening within my own application, I was not able to reproduce the problem in Codesandbox, I believe that is due to the "real-time" updating of React compared to the sandbox version.

My question mostly relates to whether you can see any issues that may be caused within my "Get random fighter" function. I was wondering if the "While" loop may be the issue

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "real-time" updating of React... the codesandbox is running React. Is the sandbox running a different version of React than you? What version are you using in your project. Sidenote: I don't think this would be an issue.

Comment: well, in ur real app, do u fill the key attribute?

Comment: I did point out that there's an edgecase where your logic could select the same random matching index and keep looping for a bit, which could be blocking the main thread. Would you like a suggested solution to eliminate this edgecase?

Comment: I have updated the codesandbox to represent my application more. It is this way that I handle redirecting and so on, I am experiencing an issue on codesandbox that does not load my component correctly upon redirecting. It seems like it freezes after redirecting has happened. This is most likely the same issue that I am experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential issue I see is that your while loop could potentially block the main thread when it keeps selecting a `randomIndex` that is equal to the found `selectedIndex`.

Here is a suggested edit to have a guaranteed `O(n)` runtime, where `n` is the "amount" of random selections you want to make.

1. Remove matching `selected` object from list of possible random selections
2. Create an array of length `amount` and map it to `n` "amount" random selections.

Code:

```
function getRandomFighters(amount, selected) {
  const dataCopy = [
    { id: 1, label: "Test1" },
    { id: 2, label: "Test2" },
    { id: 3, label: "Test3" },
    { id: 4, label: "Test4" },
    { id: 5, label: "Test5" }
  ].filter((el) => el.id !== selected.id); // <-- remove selected

  const fighters = [...Array(Math.min(amount, dataCopy.length)).keys()].map(
    () => {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dataCopy.length);
      return dataCopy.splice(randomIndex, 1).pop();
    }
  );

  return fighters;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick!! Such a nice implementation, and it makes so much sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AliÖztürk Oh, interesting. I was playing around with what I thought was your updated sandbox and was still seeing some issues, but it seemed more related to the page not rendering versus any sort of UI freezing. Glad this works for you and resolves your issue. Cheers!